# Librería gráfica para .net para 3D que maneje hilos (threads)

Tags: .net, 3d

Busco una librería gráfica que me permita programar con hilos (**threads**). 
Tengo que hacer una aplicación que me permita mostrar en pantalla un varias líneas en **3D**, así como la posición de varios objetos a la vez y en tiempo real.

Debe ser una librería de alto nivel, **Open Source** y al menos para **Windows**.

¿Qué librería gráfica para .Net o software me permitiría hacer esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traducción de:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750973/simple-3d-graphics-in-c-sharp

La librería mas fácil de utilizar es probablement [WPF 3D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms747437%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Este es un sistema de gráficos de "modo retenido", por lo que si no tienes grandes necesidades (por ejemplo: shaders especiales para efectos, etc), es muy fácil de configurar y usar.

De lo contrario, para un sistema 3D más elaborado, [XNA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA),puede ser más apropiado. Esto será más trabajo de configuración, pero te dará mucho más control.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque quizá esté un poco verde, quizá te ayude la librería [UrhoSharp](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/urho/) de Xamarin.